# ITEXSHARP: Asterisk in Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working and modifying existing code and I am new in Itextsharp. As I review the code I see a particular line in the code(check below), What is the use of asterisk(*) in this particular code? Does it get all the file that has a name "_Contract"?

```
string[] SourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDF_Temporary/"), UserName + "_Contract*.pdf");
```

Comment: Yes, it gets all the pdf files which starts with ` UserName + "_Contract"`

Comment: Thank you @RupeshPandey, does it also automatically sort the files that it get or it just first get the first/last one that inside then follow the next one?

Comment: @Ping Shouldn't a quick search for `Directory.GetFiles` on msdn give you the answer?

Comment: @Ping I believe files retrieved are sorted by name.

Comment: Thank You @RupeshPandey and mkl for your help. Really appreciated.